# How can I delete a key in a nested Javascript object with a dynamic number of properties and without eval?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, nested, eval, javascript-objects

I am looking to delete a specific key from a nested Javascript object based on a list of dynamic properties. Here is an example of what I mean:

This is a sample object:

```
employees: [
    {
        name: "John",
        id: 1234567890,
        salary: 60000
    },
    {
        name: "Jack",
        id: 0987654321,
        salary: 55000
    }
],
location: {
    building: {
        address: "111 Main St"
    }
}
```

I am looking to delete the `address` key when I am provided an array of `['location', 'building', 'address']`

When I say "dynamic" I mean that I could also be provided with an array of `['employees', 1]` so I cannot rely on a set number of nested properties.

The only approach that works for me right now is to use the dreaded `eval`, which is not a permanent solution since the Javascript objects that I am reading are written by users.

```
let jsObject = ... // the object shown above
let properties = ['location', 'building', 'address']
let evalString = ''
for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){
    evalString += '[\''+properties[i]+'\']'
}
eval('delete jsObject'+evalString)
```

What is an alternative to `eval` that will accomplish this same goal?

Comment: `let innerMost = jsObject; for (let i = 0; i < properties.length - 1; i++) { innerMost = innerMost[properties[i]]; }; delete innerMost[properties[properties.length - 1]];`

Comment: I thought I tried that earlier, but I must not have set the loop for the right number of iterations. That works just fine, thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you want to mutate the original object or produce a new object with the property deleted? If the latter, you can transform your list of strings into a list of lenses, compose the lenses to get one lens, and use that lens to do the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the object by the keys and save the last key for deleting the object with that key.

```js
function deleteKey(object, keys) {
    var last = keys.pop();
    delete keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k], object)[last];
    return object;
}

var object = { employees: [{ name: "John", id: '1234567890', salary: 60000 }, { name: "Jack", id: '0987654321', salary: 55000 }], location: { building: { address: "111 Main St" } } };

console.log(deleteKey(object, ['location', 'building', 'address']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break your array into everything except the last element, get a reference to that and the call `delete` on the object using the last element. You can use `reduce` to easily build the object reference. You need to be careful with arrays because you can't use `delete` without leaving an empty slot — `delete` doesn't change the length.

Here's the basic idea:

```js
function deleteProp(obj, keys){
    let prop = keys.pop()                     // get last key
    let c =  keys.reduce((a, c) => a[c], obj) // get penultimate obj
    if (Array.isArray(c)) c.splice(prop, 1)   // if it's an array, slice
    else delete c[prop]                       // otherwise delete

}

// Delete address
let obj = {employees: [{name: "John",id: 1234567890,salary: 60000},{name: "Jack",id: 0987654321,salary: 55000}],location: {building: {address: "111 Main St"}}}

deleteProp(obj, ['location', 'building', 'address'])
console.log(obj)

//Delete employee 1
obj = {employees: [{name: "John",id: 1234567890,salary: 60000},{name: "Jack",id: 0987654321,salary: 55000}],location: {building: {address: "111 Main St"}}}

deleteProp(obj, ['employees', 1])
console.log(obj)

//Delete employee 1 id
obj = {employees: [{name: "John",id: 1234567890,salary: 60000},{name: "Jack",id: 0987654321,salary: 55000}],location: {building: {address: "111 Main St"}}}

deleteProp(obj, ['employees', 1, 'id'])
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

This method accepts an object and an array of properties, and removes the inner most property as required

```
function remove(obj, props) {
    delete props.slice(0, -1).reduce((init, curr) => init && init[curr], obj)[[...props].pop()];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that i'm sure could be trimmed down a bit but it explains each step and you should be able to see whats happening in it:

```js
let jsObject = {
  employees: [{
      name: "John",
      id: 1234567890,
      salary: 60000
    },
    {
      name: "Jack",
      id: 0987654321,
      salary: 55000
    }
  ],
  location: {
    building: {
      address: "111 Main St"
    }
  }
};

let properties = ['location', 'building', 'address'];

// we use this to traverse the object storing the parent
let parent = null;
// run over each property in the array
for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
  // check if this is the last property  and we have the parent object
  if (i + 1 == properties.length && parent)
    delete parent[properties[i]]; // just delete the property from the object
  else if (parent === null)
    parent = jsObject[properties[i]] // set the initial parent
  else
    parent = parent[properties[i]] // set the parent to the property in the existing object
}
// log the output
console.log(jsObject);
```

You are going to want to throw error handling and checks to make sure you don't end up outside the object as well.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the object that contains the property you want to delete, then delete it:

```js
let jsObject = {
  employees: [
    {
      name: "John",
      id: 1234567890,
      salary: 60000
    },
    {
      name: "Jack",
      id: 0987654321,
      salary: 55000
    }
  ],
  location: {
    building: {
      address: "111 Main St"
    }
  }
};

let properties = ['location', 'building', 'address'];

let innerMost = jsObject;
for (let i = 0; i < properties.length - 1; i++) {
  if (typeof innerMost !== "object" || innerMost === null) {
    innerMost = null;
    break;
  }
  innerMost = innerMost[properties[i]];
};

if (
  innerMost !== null            &&
  typeof innerMost === "object" &&
  properties.length > 0         &&
  innerMost.hasOwnProperty(properties[properties.length - 1])
) {
  delete innerMost[properties[properties.length - 1]];
  console.log(jsObject);
} else console.log("Invalid path");
```